# Transaction on Android/iOS devices for Flutter apps

Tags: android, ios, stripe-payments, applepay, google-pay

I am very new to monetary transaction on Android and iOS devices. On my flutter app I am trying to implement payment options to enable consumers buy products via the app. Now, I am aware of the following:

1. Both Apple and Google charge almost 30% of any transaction for in-app and subscription within an app on their platform. And, if Apple or Google finds out we are using any other form of payment then they can remove or ban our app from their platform.
2. On the other hand, if I go for Apple or Google pay for payment for purchases then Apple or Google only charges 0.025% of the total transaction, which is fair.

My question is as follows:

1. Using flutter I am trying to build a shopping platform where sellers can sell their product via the app and the user can buy the product directly from the app. So, if we go by the rule of Apple/Google taking almost 30% cut from the transaction then the price of the product goes incredibly high, whereas, if Google Pay/Apple Pay is implemented as part of the payment option then the price of the product can still be decent. So, how to implement the payment transaction (which service to use and why)???
2. Can I also use Stripe as well as payment option or else Apple/Google can ban or remove my app?
3. Anyone else worked on something similar can you please share your decision making process on the topic?

Any insight and justification  on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Reminder: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/295004) and [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/295004).

Comment: The question you need to consider is are you delivering real world good and services or digital goods and services. If you sell a table that is delivered physically or tickets for concert you attend in person then you **cannot** use in-app purchase. You **must** use some other payment system. If you sell virtual goods such as unlocking content for a game, unlocking functionality in the app or a ticket for a concert that you view in the app you **must** use in app purchase.

Answer (score 1):

As @Paulw11 mentioned, the method for collecting payments is determined by the types of goods or services that are being sold.

In general, digital goods and services **must** use the platform's respective in-app billing systems which are subject to the fees that you mention, while other goods and services are free to use other payment methods. Even though you aren't required to use Google Pay/Apple Pay for non digital goods and services, these payment options tend to have a better user experience and higher conversion rates when compared to typical checkout forms.

**Assuming that your shopping platform sells physical goods**, see answers below:

> 1. Using flutter I am trying to build a shopping platform where sellers can sell their product via the app and the user can buy the product directly from the app. So, if we go by the rule of Apple/Google taking almost 30% cut from the transaction then the price of the product goes incredibly high, whereas, if Google Pay/Apple Pay is implemented as part of the payment option then the price of the product can still be decent. So, how to implement the payment transaction (which service to use and why)???

The 30% service fee won't apply as non-digital goods/services are being sold. You are free to use any other payment service in this case.

> 2. Can I also use Stripe as well as payment option or else Apple/Google can ban or remove my app?

Yes, you can use Stripe as this should not violate the app store policies.

See also [Google's Payments policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9858738?hl=en).